# Howto upload a file encoded in UCS-2 Little Endian into a Mysql table in UTF-8

Tags: mysql, utf-8, ucs2

I have a csv file encoded in UCS-2 Little Endian which I would like to upload into my MySQL table which is encoded in UTF-8 - default collation.  I'm curious as to what the best approach is.  If I need to write a script I can do that although I'm hoping there is a simple solution!

Thanks,
AFrieze

Comment: well... convert ucs-2 file to utf-8 :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Windows: Use Notepad++, Encoding menu / Convert to UTF-8 without BOM
- Linux: Use `recode` utility: `recode ucs2..utf8 thefile.csv`

Then `mysqlimport --default-character-set utf8 ...` (usual stuff)

Comment: Note: Editor may not recognize the source encoding, so before the conversion it would be a good idea to set the source encoding.

Comment: @Karlois Notepad++ usually does (always for me yet). If not Encoding menu / Encode in UCS-2 LittleEndian and then Convert to....

Comment: Ok this got me halfway there!  When I try to upload into Mysql, i'm getting this|  Error: 1265, Data truncated for column 'idnumber' at row 1, when using table: test_table | Which makes me think I'm still doing something wrong

Comment: Your CSV has header, hasn't it? Check that all database fields with "not null" property are supported in every line. That's debugging from now on...